# How to append Nginx IP to X-Forwarded-For in Kubernetes Nginx Ingress Controller

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I’’m wondering “How to append Nginx IP to X-Forwarded-For”

I added snippet in Ingress annotation.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ing
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For "$remote_addr, $server_addr";
```

But it seems to double set in nginx.conf.

```
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For        $remote_addr;
...
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For "$remote_addr, $server_addr";
```

So my backend server will get two `X-Forwarded-For`

Anyone knows “How to disable the proxy_set_header part generated by Nginx Ingress Controller”?

```
        proxy_set_header X-Request-ID           $req_id;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP              $remote_addr;

        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For        $remote_addr;

        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host       $best_http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port       $pass_port;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto      $pass_access_scheme;

        proxy_set_header X-Scheme               $pass_access_scheme;
```

Comment: you want one or you want to turn off both?

Comment: I want one and it set in ingress annotation

Comment: Try setting use-forwarded-headers to false https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/configmap/#use-forwarded-headers

Comment: Other option try hide-headers https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/configmap/#hide-headers

Comment: `use-forwarded-headers` default: false

Comment: `hide-headers` is hiding response headers. Not request headers.

Comment: Did you had time to check my answer? It helped you to solve your problem? If yes, please consider to accept and upvote it. [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your configuration snippet is not being doubled, actually what is happening is that `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For        $remote_addr;` is already set by default when you deploy NGINX Controller in your cluster.

In order to disable this default setting, you need to use a [custom template](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/custom-template/).

By doing this, you can have a nginx.conf free of `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For        $remote_addr;` so you can set it as you need using the annotation you have described.

Comment: How does this make sense? If that was already set, then why isn't that header set to `remote_addr` which is surely the real client IP?

Answer (score 8):

The accepted answer **is not working** for me. You just need to add the below **annotation** to the **ingress** object;

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      more_set_headers "X-Forwarded-For $http_x_forwarded_for";
```

**for testing;**

```
❯ curl -I https://example.com/path/here

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
cache-control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Date: Sat, 13 Mar 2021 08:52:02 GMT
expires: 0
pragma: no-cache
vary: Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers
X-Forwarded-For: 88.888.8.8
Connection: keep-alive
```

Comment: This does not seem to work for me. It seems the headers get removed for some reason, if I change it to another header name it works fine.

Answer (score 5):

Just for people with a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69403837) who end up here, an alternative (perhaps cleaner) solution, if you're deploying [ingress-nginx](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/) controller using Helm is to set both `compute-full-forwarded-for` and `use-forwarded-headers` to `true` in your `values.yml`. No need for additional configurations in the Ingress (like the one in the question).