# How to use Tomcat RemoteIpFilter in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, tomcat

**Objective**: get the remote address of users (i.e. `request.getRemoteAddr()`) in Spring Boot web applications.

Introduction:
As known, the `getRemoteAddr` method returns the address of the immediate caller which might be the proxy server or any other servers in between the original user and the final destination server (if there's any). To find the real address of the user, one needs to look into other headers (e.g. `X-Forwarded-For`). However I found that Tomcat (which is our web container) has a filter called `RemoteIpFilter` that takes care of this issue by copying the original address, stored in another header (e.g. `X-Forwarded-For`) back so that calling `request.getRemoteAddr()` gives you the originl address.

I added the filter to the code and everything works just fine:

```java
@Bean
FilterRegistrationBean<RemoteIpFilter> remoteIpFilter() {
    val filter = new FilterRegistrationBean<>(new RemoteIpFilter());
    filter.addUrlPatterns("/*");
    return filter;
}
```

However, there's an issue; when the request is a multipart one, Spring rejects it with:

```
The request was rejected because the header value "multipart/mixed; boundary="----=_Part_0_blahblah"; charset=utf-8" is not allowed.
```

I can see that the exception is thrown because `FilterChainProxy` filter of Spring wraps the request in `StrictFirewalledRequest` that in turn, has some checks regarding what is allowed and what is not (e.g. the above content-type is not allowed).

I couldn't find a proper solution for the above issue, other than putting the `RemoteIpFilter` filter before `FilterChainProxy` filter:

```java
// right before the tracing filter!
filter.setOrder(SleuthWebProperties.TRACING_FILTER_ORDER - 1);
```

**Questions**

1. Is using `RemoteIpFilter` a good idea?
2. Is there a better way to fix the above issue?
3. What's the best order number for `RemoteIpFilter`?

Thanks.

Comment: What version of Spring Boot are you using? Did you try with `server.forward-headers-strategy=NATIVE` (which adds a `RemoteIpValve`) instead of the `RemoteIpFilter`?

Comment: Hm, I did not know about that. Interestingly enough, you don't even need to set that property, since Spring Boot detects the environment (K8S) and activates the valve automatically. The issue I had was my Nginx configuration that replaces Forwarded-For header, not appending to it. Would you please post your comment as an answer or should I do it?

Comment: I can not fully explain how the `RemoteIpFilter` caused the rejection of `multipart/mixed` content, so it is better if you provide an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Piotr P. Karwasz's comment I figured out how to do this. It was not straightforward since it depends on the environment and other components (e.g. LB, reverse proxy, etc). But this is how you would go about it:

1. Don't use the `RemoteIpFilter` if you're using recent versions of Spring Boot + Tomcat. Spring Boot's got you covered by creating a `RemoteIpValve` (in `TomcatWebServerFactoryCustomizer`), if it feels the need.
2. If you're deploying on some cloud platform, chances are you don't need to do anything, because if Spring detects the platform as a cloud one, it automatically creates the value. No need to tell it explicitly. (See what `CloudPlatform.getActive(env)` returns.)
3. If you're not deploying on a cloud platform, probably you need to set at least one of the following properties:

   - `ServerProperties#forwardHeadersStrategy = NATIVE` (as Piotr suggested)
   - `ServerProperties.Tomcat.Remoteip#protocolHeader` (to anything e.g. `X-Forwarded-Proto`)
   - `ServerProperties.Tomcat.Remoteip#remoteIpHeader` (to anything e.g. `X-Forwarded-For`)
4. To see if it really worked, enabled debug log for `org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve` and you should be able to see its logs about changing host, addresses, etc.

In our case, I didn't need to do anything on Spring, since we deploy our app to K8S on which Spring creates the valve. Then why didn't I get the correct remote address? It turns out that our reverse proxy, Nginx has the default configuration:

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For        $remote_addr;
```

that essentially overwrites the original value, that is to be used by the `RemoteIpValve` to set back the remote address. In other words, the valve correctly reads `X-Forwarded-For` header but the header doesn't contain the correct value (the address of the user). Note that `$remote_addr` is not necessarily the address of the user. It might be the address of some other intermediary proxy/LB.

So you've got two options to fix this:

1. Set `ServerProperties.Tomcat.Remoteip#remoteIpHeader` to `X-Original-Forwarded-For` because that's where Nginx backs up the original value of `X-Forwarded-For` before overwriting with `$remote_addr`. (Seems like a hack to me!)
2. Configure Nginx to not touch `X-Forwarded-For` header at all. (Seems like a hack to me!)
3. Configure Nginx to append `X-Forwarded-For` instead of overwriting it.

To configure Nginx to append, you've got two options:

1. Work on something like this `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For "$remote_addr, $server_addr"` and configure Nginx to append instead of overwrite. (See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62337379) for how to do it on K8S. Though I couldn't get it working; Nginx complained about the number of arguments for `proxy-set-header` or something like that. Also I'm not sure if it's a bulletproof solution)
2. Configure your Helm chart installation values:

```yaml
config:
  "use-forwarded-headers": "true" # not true
  "compute-full-forwarded-for": "true" # not true
```

Thanks Piotr for the hint :)

PS: There's also some other notes on the new fancy header [`Forwarded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Forwarded) that is supposed to solve the whole mess, but apparently Nginx doesn't fully support it yet.

PSS: I didn't spend time figuring out why the exception is thrown or how to prevent it. That's probably for another day :)

Comment: except for the problem that this is a global configuration affecting all your ingresses.