# ingress-nginx proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port: 443

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-ingress

I have to return port 443 instead of port 80 to application that terminates on reverse proxy before ingress.

When adding

> ```
> nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
>   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port 443;
> ```

I get

> X-Forwarded-Port: 80
>
> X-Forwarded-Port: 443

in my header, I need to remove the port 80 for it to work

Comment: You could try the workarounds provided here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62337379/how-to-append-nginx-ip-to-x-forwarded-for-in-kubernetes-nginx-ingress-controller